# Llamar a un método y añadir funcionalidad desde otra clase

Tags: java

estoy haciendo varias tareas y una no encuentro la solución.. Pongo el enunciado:

Dado que los métodos de la interfaz Descargable fueron implementados en la clase de la cual hereda esta (LibroDigital), en principio ya no sería necesario escribir el código correspondiente a cada uno de los métodos de la interfaz. Ahora bien, el método descargar() debe ser ampliado en funcionalidad, pues además de hacer todo lo que se haga en el método homónimo de LibroDigital, los objetos Ebook aumentan de precio cada vez que se realiza una descarga: cada vez que un determinado Ebook es descargado, su precio se incrementa en 0,01 euros, siempre que no se supere el precio máximo definido para cualquier producto.

Recuerda que no debes volver a escribir todo el código del método descargar que ya fue codificado en la clase LibroDigital, sino solamente aquellas acciones que sean específicas en esta clase. Por tanto, a la hora de implementar el método deberás llevar a cabo una llamada al método homónimo de la clase padre para "aprovechar" todo lo que ya se ha implementado. Eso mismo se hará en otras clases que también sean descendientes de la clase LibroDigital y que doten a este mismo método de diferente funcionalidad en función de la clase específica de que se trate.

Mi código de descargable:

```
public interface Descargable {
    int         getSize ();
int         getNumDescargas ();
int         descarga (); }
```

Código de LibroDigital:

```
public abstract class LibroDigital extends Libro implements Descargable{

protected int tamaño;
private int numDescargas;

public static int MIN_SIZE;
public static int MAX_SIZE;


public LibroDigital (Double precio, String descripcion, String titulo, String autor, int año, int tamaño)throws IllegalArgumentException {


super(precio,descripcion, titulo, autor, año);

if (MIN_SIZE < 20)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Tamaño fuera de rango: " + tamaño + " kb");
if (MAX_SIZE > 65535)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Tamaño fuera de rango: " + tamaño + " kb");

this.tamaño=tamaño; }
@Override
public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "tamaño: " + tamaño + " numDescargas: " + numDescargas;
    
}

@Override
public int getSize() {
 return tamaño;
}

@Override
public int getNumDescargas() {
    return numDescargas;
}

public int descargar(){
    numDescargas++; 
    return numDescargas;
}
```

Y código de EBook:

```
public class EBook extends LibroDigital implements Descargable{

private String codificacion;




public EBook (Double precio, String descripcion, String titulo, String autor, int año, int tamaño, String codificacion)throws IllegalArgumentException {


super(precio,descripcion, titulo, autor, año, tamaño); }

@Override
public String toString(){
    return super.toString() + "codificación: " + codificacion; }


public int descargar(){
    try{
        precio = precio + 0.1;
    }
    finally{
        precio >= Ebook.MAX_PRECIO;
    }
    return (int) precio; } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que estás intentando incrementar el precio del Ebook en 0,01 euros cada vez que se descarga, pero sin superar el precio máximo. Aquí hay una corrección en el método `descargar()` de la clase `EBook` para lograrlo:

```
public class EBook extends LibroDigital implements Descargable {

private String codificacion;

public EBook(Double precio, String descripcion, String titulo, String autor, int año, int tamaño, String codificacion) throws IllegalArgumentException {
super(precio, descripcion, titulo, autor, año, tamaño);
this.codificacion = codificacion;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
return super.toString() + "codificación:
" + codificacion;
}

@Override
public int descargar() {
super.descargar(); // Llama al método descargar() de la clase LibroDigital

if (precio + 0.01 <= Producto.MAX_PRECIO) { // Asegúrate de que no se supere el precio máximo
precio += 0.01;
}

return (int) precio;
}
}
```

He realizado los siguientes cambios:

1. Agregué `this.codificacion = codificacion;` en el constructor de `EBook` para asignar el valor de la variable `codificacion`.
2. Cambié el método `descargar()` para que primero llame al método `descargar()` de la clase `LibroDigital` usando `super.descargar();`.
3. Cambié el bloque final de bloque con una condición if para verificar si el precio agregado es mayor que el precio máximo antes de agregar.

Comment: muchas gracias!!